# Why are the results of these two commands different?

Tags: linux, wildcard

The result of this command（ls -d [!0-99]*） already contains this command（ls -d [!0-100]*）.But in my mind, the results of these two commands should be the same.Who can help me explain the result of the second command?

```
jack@DESKTOP-KRIB7TB:~$ ls -d [!0-99]*
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k
jack@DESKTOP-KRIB7TB:~$ ls -d [!0-100]*
2   25  30  36  41  47  52  58  63  69  74  8   85  90  96  c  i
20  26  31  37  42  48  53  59  64  7   75  80  86  91  97  d  j
21  27  32  38  43  49  54  6   65  70  76  81  87  92  98  e  k
22  28  33  39  44  5   55  60  66  71  77  82  88  93  99  f
23  29  34  4   45  50  56  61  67  72  78  83  89  94  a   g
24  3   35  40  46  51  57  62  68  73  79  84  9   95  b   h
```

Answer (score 2):

The `[...]` syntax in a [glob](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) is a per-character match, not a numeric range. `[a-c]` is the same as `[abc]`, for instance. You can have multiple ranges or individual characters in a block, so `[a-cfh-k]` is the same as `[abcfhijk]`.

So `[!0-99]` is the same as `[!01234567899]` (notice the redundant `9`), whereas `[!0-100]` is the same as `[!0100]`, thereby only matching `0`s and `1`s.

You can list all non-digit directories with `ls -d [!0-9]*`, but I don't know that there's a robust way (with globs and `ls`) to list directories with names that are numerals greater than 100.